# Login to local session via remote desktop

Tags: gnome, xorg, xrdp

(Ubuntu 22.10)
I was unable to find any useful answers online, I've seen people doing it with VNC, but i couldn't get that working.

I'm aware of the gnome remote desktop, but by the look of it, I cannot even connect if the machine has a local session running.
I found GRD to be annoying since the keyboard layout never matched correctly no matter what I did on the host or client machine

(Edit)
If it's not really possible, is it possible to have Xorg user automatically signed in on boot, then connect to that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you might have to pay for that. You need to also setup a few other things as well.

1. Setup auto loging via GDM.
2. Install [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en-us/)
3. Goto Extras -> Options and check the box next to "Start TeamViewer with system"
4. Give your system a unique ID and setup for remote loging via setting a password (on teamviewer).
5. Now you can always connect to your desktop remotely.

Disclaimer: You most probably will need to pay for two licenses. It is free for personal use though.

Comment: With a physical virtual display emulator, this is perfect